Where is java keyStore
Where is java keyStore
I'm trying to deepen my understanding of Java by reading the code of other applications. While doing so, I came across something in Java called java.security.KeyStore. After researching, I found out that it is a storage mechanism for keys. However, what I can't figure out is where exactly this key storage file is located within the application. Is it an actual file or something else?
I tried looking for it in /data/data/package_name/files, but I couldn’t find any clear file related to it.

where did you put it? For all we know, you forgot to add it.

No I exactly reverse engineering an app

@user19680179 the keystore position is specified by the code that loads it. Look in the code, you should see a call to load.

It call null KeyStore.load(null)

Please [edit] your question to include a [example] so we can see the full context, since it depends on the keystore implementation you're using. Chances are it's keeping it in memory, not in a file.

Is it the cacert file you are looking for? \jre\lib\security
